# Geting data from 2 differnt tables and joining them sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query where I need to list client names and their addresses. the problem I have is that the data is spread into two tables Client & Client_Address. I am new to SQL and databases so this might be an easy task to do I'm unsure. I have done some research and have thought about using inner-join but unsure how to implement it in my scenario.
the contents of the client table are;

```
Client (ClientNum, ClientName)
```

the contents for Client_Address are;

```
Client_Address (ClientNum, addressType, street, city, state, postcode)
```

I need to write a query that includes the ClientName from the client table and I also need to include addressType, street, city, state and postcode from the Client_Address table.

the desired output would be;

```
clientName, addressType, street, city, state and postcode
```

See bellow my current code:

```
SELECT clientname, addressType, street, city, state, postcode
FROM   client , Client_Address
ORDER BY clientName ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written a cross product, you haven't specified how the rows are related between the two tables. Use a proper join:

```
SELECT clientname, addressType, street, city, state, postcode
FROM client AS c
JOIN client_address AS a ON c.clientnum = a.clientnum
ORDER BY clientName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply join query as below:

```
SELECT C.clientname, CA.addressType, CA.street, CA.city, CA.state, CA.postcode
FROM   client AS C INNER JOIN Client_Address AS CA
ON C.clientnum = CA.clientnum
ORDER BY C.clientName ASC
```